# angularjs how to pass argument to directive

Tags: angularjs

Here is the html part:

```
<th class="widget-header">
  <label class="formwidget-fieldlabel">Question Title</label>
</th>
```

i am trying to do is to make an directive for repeat using it.

But, I have no idea on how to make the "Question Title" part as an argument, 
Seems the following codes does not work.

```
app.directive 'thdatahead', () ->
    restrict: 'E'
        scope:
          title: '='
    template: '<th class="widget-header">' + '<label class="formwidget-fieldlabel">title</label></th>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that you're looking for is called [transclusion](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) which basically allows you to take the innards of the element your directive lives on and place it where you want inside your directive.

Declaration:

```
restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
```

Usage in directive:

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

So in your example above, you'll need to use your directive, I'd suggest using this as an attribute here because `thdatahead` is not a valid tag under table or thead.

```
<thdatahead class="widget-header">
  <label class="formwidget-fieldlabel">Question Title</label>
</thdatahead>

app.directive 'thdatahead', () ->
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<th class="widget-header"><div ng-transclude></div></th>'
```

The best description I heard of transclusion directives was from ng-conf, where the speaker described it as a picture frame. ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMkd0nYmLzY), reference @ ~28min but the whole thing is pretty good)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are trying to pass to the directive is a variable, you can pass it as an attribute of the directive (in this case there's no need for transclusion):

```
app.directive 'thdatahead', () ->
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {title: '='},
    template: '<th class="widget-header"><label class="formwidget-fieldlabel">{{title}}</label></th>'
```

You were missing the `{{ }}` binding for scope variables. You can pass the `title` variable to the directive when you instantiate your directive:

```
<thdatahead title="scopeVariableForTitle"></thdatahead>
```

Of course you'll need a controller variable:

```
$scope.scopeVariableForTitle = 'Question Title'
```

Comment: If you tell why not I can find another way that suits you better =)